# Logging and troubleshooting HTTP 502s (Request Timeouts) within Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure

We had an issue this week where a non-performant SQL query caused an app to start sending 502's as the time it took to run the query passed the Azure App Service request timeout setting (which seems to NOT be user definable)

I'm trying to find a way to detect and alert on these issues. I've gone thru the microsoft documentation but only find recommendations like "scale out" - If I look at Application Insights it doesn't seem to log the 502 since, from the app's perspective, the script ran successfully. Is there a way to log there instances with some context to fix non-performant scripts before a user calls in about a 502? The only option I see is to NOT use the built in load balancing/app gateway features of Azure App Service and roll a separate load balancer/gateway to have more control over it..

Comment: I am facing a problem like that too. Seems that this error is on IIS level, this is why Application Insights is not capturing it.

Comment: Have you been able to check the metrics on the app service plan?

Comment: @DreadedFrost The metrics don't seem to have an option to show HTTP status codes..

Comment: Gotcha.  Couple things that could be tried, full disclosure I have limited experience in these steps.  First here is a [feedback on this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12470307-lack-of-the-log-to-investigate-the-http-502-errors)
In addition try turning on some of the advanced logging in the App Service by going to [App Service Logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) under Monitoring  and turn on some of the advanced logging.  Another option is to turn on Log Stream but that might return something only in real time.

Comment: @DreadedFrost . We have advanced logging on and use the log stream. Both seem to report at the VM instance level, and do not include the load balancer errors.

Comment: Is it an async method?